# Get a vocabulary of each row in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

i have this dataset

```
    id       cuisine                 ingredients                                    lowercase
0   10259   greek   [romaine lettuce, black olives, grape tomatoes...   romaine lettuce black olives grape tom...
1   25693   southern_us [plain flour, ground pepper, salt, tomatoes, g...   plain flour ground pepper salt toma...
2   20130   filipino    [eggs, pepper, salt, mayonaise, cooking oil, g...   eggs pepper salt mayonaise cooki...
3   22213   indian  [water, vegetable oil, wheat, salt]                     water vegetable oil wheat salt
4   13162   indian  [black pepper, shallots, cornflour, cayenne pe...   black pepper shallots cornflour cay...
...  ...     ...                       ...                                         ...
```

I want to get the vocabulary of each cuisine (unique tokens) but i don' know how. I tried to groupby cuisine but the result is not what i expect i also tried to iterate the lowercase column but i can't find how to combine the result with the cuisine column. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` and then use groupby by applying a set:

```
df.explode('ingridients').groupby('cuisine')['ingridients'].apply(set)
```

This will return a `pd.Series` where the index is the cuisine and the values are a `set` with the dictionary.